# Ignore Issues in Blocks

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Our Java files analyzed on SQ contain blocks of automatically generated code. Such a block starts with

```
// @UKA_GENERATION_START@
```

and ends with

```
// @UKA_GENERATION_END@
```

Code lines between them should be ignored by SQ.

Site http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus describes in the chapter 'Ignore Issues in Blocks' how it can be done. Parameter `sonar.issue.ignore.block` should be used.

In our environment we use Maven for project build and analysis. In the project's POM we set the following parameters:

```
<sonar.issue.ignore.block>e1</sonar.issue.ignore.block>
<sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp>\/\/ @UKA_GENERATION_START@</sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp>
<sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp>\/\/ @UKA_GENERATION_END@</sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp>
```

(Regular expressions matching above strings).

Unfortunately, SQ doesn't exclude code blocks between `// @UKA_GENERATION_START@` and `// @UKA_GENERATION_END@` from the analysis!
Do you have an idea, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set this in the UI, not in parameters. There was already a warning about this in the docs, but I've made it more noticeable.

Comment: It seems to work well by setting these values as parameters, not in the UI but on the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

How about simplifying your regex by leaving out the `//` characters? The following configuration should work perfectly fine:

```
sonar.issue.ignore.block=e1
sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp=@UKA_GENERATION_START@
sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp=@UKA_GENERATION_END@
```

Configured as above, issues between the start and end tags will be ignored

```
// @UKA_GENERATION_START@

System.out.println("Hello world!");

// @UKA_GENERATION_END@
```

Or in more detail... in the following example, lines 1 and 5 will raise a Sonar issue, while lines 2 - 4 will be ignored:

```
1:  System.out.println("Hello world!");
2:  System.out.println("Hello world!");   // @UKA_GENERATION_START@
3:  System.out.println("Hello world!");
4:  System.out.println("Hello world!");   // @UKA_GENERATION_END@
5:  System.out.println("Hello world!");
```